# html link value retrieve by Js ajax send to php

Tags: php, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a html link with a value inside like this.

```
<a data-toggle='modal' data-id='1' href='#myModal' class='marker' title='Edit'>Link</a>
```

I have a Js script that trigger a php that I want to send the value data-id

```
<script>
    $(document).on("click", ".marker", function () {
        var myBookId = $(this).data('id');

        $.ajax({
        type: "post",
            url: "update.php", // 
            data: myBookId,
            success: function(msg) {
                $("#thanks").html(msg)
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("failure");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And in my php I have this

```
if (isset($_POST['myBookId'])) {
    $emp_id = strip_tags($_POST['myBookId']);
    echo $emp_id;
```

But something is wrong the value is not pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is on the params of the AJAX call. Try this way:

```
data: { myBookId: myBookId },
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('.marker')click(function(){

var myBookId = $().attr('data-id');

 $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "update.php", // 
                data: myBookId,
                success: function(msg){
                    $("#thanks").html(msg)

                },
                error: function(){
                    alert("failure");
                }
    });
return false;

});
```